# function for imagefilledrectangle with rounded corners

Tags: php

I'm willing to create an image with certain text using the following code

```
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(320, 80);

$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 59, 89, 152);
$sky = imagecolorallocate($im, 219, 241, 255);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 79, $sky);

$font = 'arial.ttf';

$text = "Hello world"; 

imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 10, 20, $blue, $font, $text); 
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Now the out put will be as following image

this is rectangle

[image: rectangle image]

**Now**
What if i want to made to it a rounded corner 
by refer to php manual about [function imagefilledrectangle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) I've found a good comment with function said to be able to make it rounded corner

```
<?

function ImageRectangleWithRoundedCorners(&$im, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $radius, $color)
{
// draw rectangle without corners
imagefilledrectangle($im, $x1+$radius, $y1, $x2-$radius, $y2, $color);
imagefilledrectangle($im, $x1, $y1+$radius, $x2, $y2-$radius, $color);
// draw circled corners
imagefilledellipse($im, $x1+$radius, $y1+$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, $color);
imagefilledellipse($im, $x2-$radius, $y1+$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, $color);
imagefilledellipse($im, $x1+$radius, $y2-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, $color);
imagefilledellipse($im, $x2-$radius, $y2-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, $color);
}

?>
```

But didn't mention how to use ! ~ anyhelp

Comment: I assume you would call the function in place of the normal one? You'd have to add the `$radius` parameter and you should be good to go

Comment: @Pekka thanks so can you please write an answer with the full code if it possible. ~thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me try

probably

```
$x1 = top left point's x coordinate
$y1 = top left point's y coordinate
$x2 = bottom right point's x coordinate
$y2 = bottom right point's y coordinate
$radius = radius of the curve of rounded corner
```

set this data and try... good luck :)

Comment: Not working :( , I don't know why they don't give radius and border parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody needs the background behind the radius to be transparent, this function can be used (I modified the one posted by OP) =>

```
function image_rectangle_w_rounded_corners(&$im, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $radius, $color) {
    $alpha = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    
    // draw rectangle without corners
    imagefilledrectangle($im, $x1+$radius, $y1, $x2-$radius, $y2, $color);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, $x1, $y1+$radius, $x2, $y2-$radius, $color);
    
    // draw circled corners
    imagefilledellipse($im, $x1+$radius, $y1+$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, $color);
    imagefilledellipse($im, $x2-$radius, $y1+$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, $color);
    imagefilledellipse($im, $x1+$radius, $y2-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, $color);
    imagefilledellipse($im, $x2-$radius, $y2-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, $color);
    
    // alpha radius bg
    $width = imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im) - 0.01;
    
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $alpha);
    imagefill($im, $width, 0, $alpha);
    imagefill($im, 0, $height, $alpha);
    imagefill($im, $width, $height, $alpha);
}
```

Of course - transparency can be switched for any other color.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old question, but may be someone will benefit from this answer.
This is a very nice function!
Here is how to use it:

```
x1 = the horizontal x point where you want rectangle to start
x2 = the horizontal x point where you want rectangle to end
y1= the vertical y point where rectangle starts
y2 = the vertical y point where rectangle ends
```

Now the radius.
Set the radius to "half" of difference between y2 and y1

Suppose your y2 is 100, and y1 is 50, then radius will be:

```
( y2 - y1 )/2
( 100 - 50 )/2 = 25
```

Couple of examples are here:
http://vagminetech.com/rect.htm

For a wide rectangle:
x1=50 x2=250 y1=50 y2=100 r=25

For a tall rectangle
 x1=50 x2=150 y1=50 y2=150 r=50

Regards